# Project Euler #25 Python Why this wont work?

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve [this problem](http://projecteuler.net/problem=25):

> The 12th term, F<sub>12</sub>, is the first term to contain three digits.
>
> What is the first term in the Fibonacci sequence to contain 1000
>   digits?

```
check = True
mylst = [1,1]
i = 1
while check:
    if  len(str(mylst[i])) >= 1000:
        check = False
    else:
        mylst.append(mylst[i-1] + mylst[i-2])  
        i=i+1
a =str((mylst[len(mylst)-1]))
print(len(a))
print(a)
```

I seem to get correct answer for test cases 2 and 3 but my answer is not being accepted. Please help me me I am not able to understand what went wrong.

Comment: Please include the full question in your post (what is Project Euler #25?). You are far more likely to get an answer if people don't have to go to an external website and look it up themselves.

Comment: @MohammadS. No, it's the same exercise, but a different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an error in your code. If you look at the first iteration, you start with i=1 then call

```
mylst.append(mylst[i-1] + mylst[i-2])
```

Which will add `mylst[0] + mylst[-1]`. This also gives me incorrect answers (for finding the first index with 3 digits, F12. Your code gives me F18).

Obviously this is not what you want to do. You can fix it by changing the list indices you are adding together.

```
check = True
mylst = [1,1]
i = 1
while check:
    if  len(str(mylst[i])) >= 1000:
        check = False
    else:
        mylst.append(mylst[i] + mylst[i-1])  
        i=i+1
```

Then, as others have mentioned, you want the index of the answer.

```
print len(mylst)
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is the index of the fibonacci number, not the number itself.

So, if F<sub>n</sub> is the first term in the Fibonacci sequence to contain 1000 digits you need to enter the corresponding n.

Comment: His code does not give correct answers regardless. If you replace `1000` with `3` it would give index 18, not 12.

Comment: You are right, he is also generating the numbers incorrectly because of an off-by-one bug

Answer (score 1):

Because the question is what term is the first to contain 1000 digits, not which number. So, if the question was

> What is the first term in the Fibonacci sequence to contain 3 digits?

The answer would have been 12, not 144.

A general tip on Project Euler: Read the problem description carefully. And do it at least 3 times. If I had burned one calorie for each minute I've spent troubleshooting a PE problem due to a misread of the problem text, my body would probably be in a healthy shape.