# Why doesn't my Python Fibonacci sequence work properly? [Project Euler #25]

Tags: python, fibonacci

So I have been working on the Project Euler problems recently and everything has gone relatively smoothly. That is until I hit #25:

*"What is the first term in the Fibonacci sequence to contain 1000 digits?"*

The program I made (The following):

```
def main():
    x = 0
    y = 1
    z = 0
    while len(str(z)) != 1000:
        z = x + y
        x = y
        y = z
    print z
main()
```

Should give me the correct answer but I only get: 
"

1070066266382758936764980584457396885083683896632151665013235203375314520604694040621889147582489792657804694888177591957484336466672569959512996030461262748092482186144069433051234774442750273781753087579391666192149259186759553966422837148943113074699503439547001985432609723067290192870526447243726117715821825548491120525013201478612965931381792235559657452039506137551467837543229119602129934048260706175397706847068202895486902666185435124521900369480641357447470911707619766945691070098024393439617474103736912503231365532164773697023167755051595173518460579954919410967778373229665796581646513903488154256310184224190259846088000110186255550245493937113651657039447629584714548523425950428582425306083544435428212611008992863795048006894330309773217834864543113205765659868456288616808718693835297350643986297640660000723562917905207051164077614812491885830945940566688339109350944456576357666151619317753792891661581327159616877487983821820492520348473874384736771934512787029218636250627816

"

Which is the wrong answer. So I'm using the fibonacci sequence to generate the wrong 1000 digit number some how.. Can anyone help me fix it? I'm nearly out of ideas.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Project Euler #25 Python Why this wont work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803952/project-euler-25-python-why-this-wont-work)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're looking for `n` where the `nth` term has 1000 digits (not the actual number itself).

From the [question](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=025):

> The Fibonacci sequence is defined by the recurrence relation:
>
> ```
> Fn = Fn−1 + Fn−2, where F1 = 1 and F2 = 1.
> ```
>
> Hence the first 12 terms will be:
>
> ```
> F1 = 1
> F2 = 1
> F3 = 2
> F4 = 3
> F5 = 5
> F6 = 8
> F7 = 13
> F8 = 21
> F9 = 34
> F10 = 55
> F11 = 89
> F12 = 144
> ```
>
> The 12th term, F12, is the first term to contain three digits.
>
> What is the first term in the Fibonacci sequence to contain 1000
>   digits?

So for your brute force solution, just put in a counter that increments with the loop.

Comment: Extra note - there are two versions of the Fibonacci series, both identical except that one includes an initial `0`. OP seems to be generating that at first sight, but the question seems to require the older one that doesn't include the `0`. It makes no difference if the answer is the 1000-digit number, but choosing the wrong one will give an out-by-one error for the `n`.